# Scrapy doesn't bring back the elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The log, I suppose, shows no serious problem, but no elements are scraped. So, I guess the problem might be because of the XPath expressions. But, I double-checked them and simplify them as well as I could. Therefore, I really need help in finding the bugs here.

Here is the log I got:

```
2020-11-19 12:57:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-11-19 12:57:07 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-11-19 12:57:07 [scrapy.extensions.httpcache] DEBUG: Using filesystem cache storage in C:\Users\shima\projects\apple_podcasts\.scrapy\httpcache
2020-11-19 12:57:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-11-19 12:57:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/robots.txt> (referer: None) ['cached']
2020-11-19 12:57:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts-books/id1482> (referer: None) ['cached']
2020-11-19 12:57:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts-books/id1482?letter=A> (referer: https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts-books/id1482) ['cached']
2020-11-19 12:57:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/about-myself/id1494962309> (referer: https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts-books/id1482?letter=A) ['cached']
2020-11-19 12:57:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-11-19 12:57:08 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1415,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 75168,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 19, 9, 27, 8, 185767),
 'httpcache/hit': 4,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 4,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 19, 9, 27, 7, 723909)}
2020-11-19 12:57:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

To explain the functionality of this crawler, to be understood easier, since it may seem huge at first glance but it is not at all, I told my spider to go through a couple of links and each time yield some elements. Here is my spider:

```
import scrapy



class ApplePodcastSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'apple_podcast'
allowed_domains = ['podcasts.apple.com']


def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301',
            callback= self.parse_categories,dont_filter = True)



def parse_categories(self, response):
        categories=response.xpath("//ul[@class='list column first']")
        for category in categories:
            category_name=category.xpath(".//li/a/text()").get()
            category_link=category.xpath(".//li/a/@href").get()
            yield response.follow(url=category_link, callback=self.parse_sub_categories, meta={'category_name': category_name}, dont_filter=True)



def parse_sub_categories(self, response):
        category_name=response.request.meta['category_name']
        sub_categories=response.xpath("//ul[@class='list column first']/li")
        for sub_category in sub_categories:
            sub_category_name=sub_category.xpath(".//ul[@class='list top-level-subgenres']/li/a/text()").get()
            sub_category_link=sub_category.xpath(".//ul[@class='list top-level-subgenres']/li/a/@href").get()
            if sub_category_link is None:
                pass
            else:
                yield response.follow(url=sub_category_link, callback=self.parse_alphabet, meta={'category_name': category_name,'sub_category_name': sub_category_name}, dont_filter=True)
            


def parse_alphabet(self,response):
        category_name=response.request.meta['category_name']
        sub_category_name=response.request.meta['sub_category_name']
        for alphabet_link in response.xpath("//ul[@class='list alpha']/li/a/@href").getall():
            yield response.follow(url=alphabet_link, callback=self.parse_podcasts_link, meta={'category_name': category_name, 'sub_category_name': sub_category_name},dont_filter = True)
 

def parse_podcasts_link(self, response):
        category_name=response.request.meta['category_name']
        sub_category_name=response.request.meta['sub_category_name']
        for podcast_node in response.xpath("//div[@class='column first']/ul/li/a"):
            
            podcast_link = podcast_node.xpath('.//@href').get()

        for podcast_node in response.xpath("//div[@class='column']/ul/li/a"):
            
            podcast_link = podcast_node.xpath('.//@href').get()

        for podcast_node in response.xpath("//div[@class='column last']/ul/li/a"):
            
            podcast_link = podcast_node.xpath('.//@href').get()

            yield response.follow(url=podcast_link, callback=self.parse_podcasts, meta={'category_name':category_name,'sub_category_name':sub_category_name},dont_filter = True)    


def parse_podcasts(self, response):
        category_name = response.request.meta['category_name']
        sub_category_name = response.request.meta['sub_category_name']
        name = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@data-test-podcast-name])').get()
        author = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@data-test-artist-name])').get()
        podcasts = response.xpath("//div[@id='ember146']/section/div")
        for podcast in podcasts:

            if podcast.xpath(".//div[@class='l-column small-12 medium-7 large-8 small-valign-top']/div/div[2]/header/ul/li[2]/ul/li/figure/figcaption/text()[1]"):
                rate = podcast.xpath(".//div[@class='l-column small-12 medium-7 large-8 small-valign-top']/div/div[2]/header/ul/li[2]/ul/li/figure/figcaption/text()[1]").get()
            
            else:
                rate=''

            if podcast.xpath(".//div[@class='l-column small-12 medium-7 large-8 small-valign-top']/div/div[2]/header/ul/li[2]/ul/li/figure/figcaption/text()[3]"):
                rating_number = podcast.xpath(".//div[@class='l-column small-12 medium-7 large-8 small-valign-top']/div/div[2]/header/ul/li[2]/ul/li/figure/figcaption/text()[3]").get()
            
            else:
                rating_number=''
            
            if podcast.xpath(".//section[@id='ember147']/div/div/div[1]/p/text()"):
                episodes = podcast.xpath(".//section[@id='ember147']/div/div/div[1]/p/text()").get()
            
            else:
                episodes=''
            
            if podcast.xpath(".//section[@id='ember393']/div/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/div/p/text()[1]"):
                description_in_short= podcast.xpath(".//section[@id='ember393']/div/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/div/p/text()[1]").get()
            
            else:
                description_in_short=''
            
            if podcast.xpath(".//section[@id='ember393']/div/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/div/p/text()[2]"):
                description_the_rest=podcast.xpath(".//section[@id='ember393']/div/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/div/p/text()[2]").get()
            
            else:
                description_the_rest=''

            yield{
                'category_name':category_name,
                'sub_category_name':sub_category_name,
                'name':name,
                'author':author,
                'rate':rate,
                'rating_number':rating_number,
                'episodes':episodes,
                'description':f'{description_in_short}+{description_the_rest}'
            }

        next_page=response.xpath("//div[@id='content']/div[@class='padder']/div[@id='selectedgenre']/ul[@class='list paginate'][1]/li/a/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_podcasts,dont_filter = True)
```

Thanks for any help!!

---EDIT---

Here is the log I get @gangabass:

```
2020-11-22 11:18:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/bake-sale-by-nora-voutas/id1526021229> (referer: https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts-books/id1482?letter=B) ['cached']
2020-11-22 11:18:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-11-22 11:18:52 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 875349,
 'downloader/request_count': 2100,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2100,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 75683564,
 'downloader/response_count': 2100,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2100,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 22, 7, 48, 52, 286711),
 'httpcache/hit': 2100,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2101,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'request_depth_max': 4,
 'response_received_count': 2100,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2099,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2099,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2099,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2099,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 22, 7, 47, 46, 330411)}
2020-11-22 11:18:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous answer, `alphabets` returns only one item, so you are iterating over a single item, therefore it only yield the request for one letter (A in this case). When the letter A request get to `parse_podcasts_link` the selector that defines `podcast` returns empty, so there is nothing to extract links from, so the spider just ends, it never gets to the `parse_podcasts` method. Try following your spider flow in [scrapy shell](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) and you will notice all the wrong selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use this expressions for `parse_podcast`:

```
 name = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@data-test-podcast-name])').get()
 author = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@data-test-artist-name])').get()
```

For your `parse_alphabet` (as pointed by [@renatodvc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11326319/renatodvc)):

```
for alphabet_link in response.xpath("//ul[@class='list alpha']/li/a/@href").getall():
    yield response.follow(url=alphabet_link, callback=self.parse_podcasts_link, meta={'category_name': category_name, 'sub_category_name': sub_category_name},dont_filter = True)
```

For `parse_podcasts_link`:

```
for podcast_node in response.xpath("//div[@class='column first']/ul/li/a/"):
    podcast_name = podcast_node.xpath('./text()').get()
    podcast_link = podcast_node.xpath('./@href').get()
```

Comment: Thank you, @gangabass. Except for your first recommendation, I did what you said and renewed my spider code above. The problem is now, as you can see in the log in "EDIT" part, it seems everything is okay and crawled but no elements are scraped at last.

Comment: Please try my code for `parse_podcasts` because I don't have any `//div[@id="ember146"]` on my side at all (it may be some kind of random value) (that's why I don't recommend relying on it).

Comment: Sure @gangabass, I edited my spider code above, now in def parse_podcasts, I wrote "name" and "author" the same as you said. The log is still the same. It seems that the crawler goes to links and crawl the pages but doesn't scrape any element.

Comment: I changed it in the spider's code above (if I got you correctly). You can see it inside "parse_podcasts"@gangabass, otherwise, I didn't get exactly what you said.

Comment: I believe that this `podcasts = response.xpath("//div[@id='ember146']/section/div")` part of code return `None` that's why you didn't `yield` anything. Did you try to `yield` outside of this loop?

Comment: You were right! I changed the address of podcasts = response.xpath("//div[@id='ember146']/section/div") to podcasts= response.xpath("//div[@class='l-row']") and it worked!! I am so thankful for your time and energy!! @gangabass